# Getting Error While Inserting Data to Table through Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I have a table name customers, While i am inserting data in this table through Stored Procedure then i am getting error:

**Stored Procedure is as follows:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter procedure [dbo].[customerinsert_new]
(@cid int, @full_name varchar(50),@gender varchar(20),@DOB date,@age varchar(50),@marital_status varchar(20),@email varchar(50),@phone varchar(20),
@Country varchar(50),@State varchar(50),@City Varchar(50),@address varchar(100),@Height varchar(50),@weight varchar(50),@BMI varchar(50),    @Subscription int,@referral varchar(50),@joining_date date,@due_date date,
@amount_reccived varchar(50),@amount_left varchar(50),
@c_photo varchar(100),@primary_facility varchar(50),
@occupation varchar(50),@Medical_aliments varchar(200),
@know_about_sculpt varchar(50),@workout_history varchar(100),
@Fitness_goal varchar(50),@no_days_train_weekly varchar(50),
@no_hours_train_daily varchar(50),@heart_condition varchar(50),
@chest_pain varchar(50),@chest_pain_last_month varchar(50),
@lose_consciousness varchar(50),@bone_joint_problem varchar(50),
@Doctor_currently_prescribing_drugs varchar(50),
@other_reason_not_do_physical_activity varchar(50),
@emergency_name varchar(50),@emergency_relation varchar(50),
@emergency_contact varchar(50),@bid varchar(50),
@device varchar(20),@payment_remarks varchar(50),@orderno varchar(50),
@discount varchar(10),@famt varchar(50))

  as
  begin
  insert into customers values
  (@cid,@full_name,@gender,@DOB,@age,@marital_status,@email,@phone,@Country,     @State,@City,@address,@Height,@weight,@BMI,@Subscription,@referral,@joining_date,@due_date,@amount_reccived,@amount_left,@c_photo,@primary_facility,@occupation,@Medical_aliments,@know_about_sculpt,@workout_history, @Fitness_goal,  @no_days_train_weekly,@no_hours_train_daily,@heart_condition,@chest_pain,
  @chest_pain_last_month,@lose_consciousness,@bone_joint_problem,  @Doctor_currently_prescribing_drugs,@other_reason_not_do_physical_activity,
  @emergency_name,@emergency_relation,@emergency_contact,@bid,@device, @payment_remarks,@orderno,@discount,@famt)
  end
```

**and database design is as follows:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customers](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [full_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [gender] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NOT NULL,
    [marital_status] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [email] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [phone] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [address] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Height] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [weight] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BMI] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Subscription] [int] NULL,
    [referral] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [joining_date] [date] NULL,
    [due_date] [date] NULL,
    [amount_reccived] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [amount_left] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [c_photo] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [age] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [primary_facility] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [occupation] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Medical_aliments] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [know_about_sculpt] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [workout_history] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Fitness_goal] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [no_days_train_weekly] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [no_hours_train_daily] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [heart_condition] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [chest_pain] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [chest_pain_last_month] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lose_consciousness] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [bone_joint_problem] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Doctor_currently_prescribing_drugs] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [other_reason_not_do_physical_activity] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [emergency_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [emergency_relation] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [emergency_contact] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [bid] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [device] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [payment_remarks] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [orderno] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [discount] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [famt] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

**I tried to get data by profiler, and i am able to see data is coming correct, but getting error, query at profiler:**

```
exec customerinsert_new @cid='1079',@full_name='Testing',@gender='Male',@dob='2017-10-03',@age='25',@marital_status='Married',
@email='h@h.com',@phone='5',@country='India',@state='Haryana',@city='Asankhurd',@address='H.no. 720 Sector 9', @height='6.0',@weight='80',@BMI='23.92',@Subscription='3',@referral='Friend',@joining_date='2017-09-01',@due_date='2017-01-01',     @amount_reccived='1200',@amount_left='6800',@c_photo='10791.png',@primary_facility='Gym',@occupation='Na',@Medical_aliments='Na',
@know_about_sculpt='Friend',@workout_history='NA',@Fitness_goal='Fat Loss',@no_days_train_weekly='2',@no_hours_train_daily='1',     @heart_condition='No',@chest_pain='No',@chest_pain_last_month='No',@lose_consciousness='No',@bone_joint_problem='Yes',     @Doctor_currently_prescribing_drugs='No',@other_reason_not_do_physical_activity='No',@emergency_name='Mann',@emergency_relation='Na',     @emergency_contact='NA',@bid='2',@device='2',@payment_remarks='Cash',@orderno='INV2YQG2812OWX701XOE70112',@discount='0',@famt='8000'
```

in above query, like bmi is a varchar datatype field , but i am getting error:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure customerinsert_new, Line 52
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '23.90' to data type int.

and for joining_date i am getting error which is date datatype:

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure customerinsert_new, Line 52
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Following insert command insert data successfully:

```
insert into customers(cid,full_name,gender,DOB,marital_status,email,phone,Country,State,City,address,Height,weight,BMI,Subscription,referral,joining_date,
due_date,amount_reccived,amount_left,c_photo,age,primary_facility,occupation,Medical_aliments,know_about_sculpt,workout_history,Fitness_goal,no_days_train_weekly,
no_hours_train_daily,heart_condition,chest_pain,chest_pain_last_month,lose_consciousness,bone_joint_problem,Doctor_currently_prescribing_drugs,
other_reason_not_do_physical_activity,emergency_name,emergency_relation,emergency_contact,bid,payment_remarks,orderno,discount,famt)
 values('1079','Testing','Male','2017/10/23','Married','h@h.com','5','India','Haryana','Asankhurd','H.no. 720 Sector 9','6.0','80','23.90','3',
 'Friend','2017/09/11','2017/12/11','1200','6800','10791.png','25','Gym','Na','Na','Friend','NA','Fat Loss','2','1','No','No',
 'No','No','Yes','No','No','Mann','Na','NA','2','Cash','INV2YQG2812OWX701XOE70112','0','8000')
```

Comment: Both error messages are pretty straight forward and clear. What do you expect us to do about it?

Comment: Hi Zohar Peled, i just want to know that why these errors are coming, as when i am inserting data with insert command in sql server through c#, then the same data inserted successfully.

Comment: `23.90` can't be converted to `int`, and whatever string you are using can't be converted to `date` or `datetime`. Do you expect us to do the debugging for you?

Comment: Hi, When inserting data by insert command , record inserted successfully. please check insert command at last of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a really good reason for your design... Using varchar(xy) for almost all your columns will be a great draw back in future... You should always place data in appropriate types!

The difference between the working command and your posted one is the **explicitly stated column list**. You should **never ever** rely on the columns to be in the expected order! No `SELECT *` and no `INSERT INTO SomeTable [VALUES|SELECT]`!

```
insert into customers values
(@cid,@full_name,@gender,@DOB,@age,@m
```

Place the column names in the correct order like in the later posted command:

```
insert into customers(col1, col2, ...) values
(@cid,@full_name,@gender,@DOB,@age,@m ...
```

I'm pretty sure, that order of columns of your table's DDL differs. After `c_photo` there's no `age`. You are not inserting the values to the columns you think you do.

Did you change your table recently? Your procedure might need a recompile in this case...

Comment: Not exactly the same, but very related: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list

Comment: thanks Shnugo, you find the exact cause. now it is working fine.

Comment: I accepted your answer, But my votes are not displaying publicly.